# To serve other than index.html using webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

In public folder, index.html, altIndex.html are there. I want to serve altIndex.html.

when webpack devserver is run, it serves index.html. as per below config.

```
 devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    historyApiFallback: true
    }
  }
```

as per https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/ below config doesn't work. still serves index.html

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'altIndex.html'
    }
  }
```

below config also, doesn't work. still serves index.html.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'altIndex.html',
      rewrites: [
        { from: /^\/$/, to: '/altIndex.html' }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**how to serve html other than index.html from public folder?**

webpack.config.json

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    historyApiFallback:true
  }
};
```

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback, should that be `index: '/altIndex.html'`, i.e. with a leading slash?

Comment: `historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/altIndex.html'
    }` didnot work. still rendering index.html

Answer (score 0):

try this (as stated [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverindex)):

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  index: 'altIndex.html',
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: 'altIndex.html'
  }
}
```

Comment: tried  `devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  index: 'altIndex.html',
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: 'altIndex.html'
  }
}` didnot work